# How are command buffers ordered, for barriers' purposes, within a single vkQueueSubmit call?

Tags: synchronization, memory-barriers, vulkan

Vulkan specification (1.0.27) says (in section **6.5. Pipeline Barriers**):

> Each element of the pMemoryBarriers, pBufferMemoryBarriers and pImageMemoryBarriers arrays specifies two halves of a memory dependency, as defined above. [...]
>
> If vkCmdPipelineBarrier is called outside a render pass instance, then the first set of commands is all prior commands submitted to the queue and recorded in the command buffer and the second set of commands is all subsequent commands recorded in the command buffer and submitted to the queue.

(The wording is funny; if interpreted literally it seems to say that a barrier only orders commands within one command buffer, leaving the "submitted to the queue" parts redundant perhaps; but if interpreted a little more fuzzily it seems to be aiming to say that the barrier orders commands both within its command buffer and within a queue.  Other Stack Overflow pages point me to the following, which seems to confirm the latter interpretation:  https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/300 )

My question, then.  Suppose you've got four command buffers being submitted in two batches of two, all in one `vkQueueSubmit` command:

```
VkSubmitInfo nextSubmitInfo;
nextSubmitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
nextSubmitInfo.pNext = nullptr;
nextSubmitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 0;
nextSubmitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask = nullptr;
nextSubmitInfo.pWaitSemaphores = nullptr;
nextSubmitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 0;
nextSubmitInfo.pSignalSemaphores = nullptr;

std::vector<VkCommandBuffer> commandBuffersAB{commandBufferA, commandBufferB};
std::vector<VkCommandBuffer> commandBuffersCD{commandBufferC, commandBufferD};

std::vector<VkSubmitInfo> submitInfo;

nextSubmitInfo.commandBufferCount = commandBuffersAB.size();
nextSubmitInfo.pCommandBuffers = commandBuffersAB.data();
submitInfo.emplace_back(nextSubmitInfo);

nextSubmitInfo.commandBufferCount = commandBuffersCD.size();
nextSubmitInfo.pCommandBuffers = commandBuffersCD.data();
submitInfo.emplace_back(nextSubmitInfo);

df.vkQueueSubmit(queue, submitInfo.size(), submitInfo.data(), VK_NULL_HANDLE);
```

Suppose each of the four command buffers includes a barrier and some action commands (which according to the specification are "commands that perform actions (e.g. draw/dispatch)").  I tend to naively expect, then, that the barriers will perceive the command buffers as being submitted in alphabetical order, so that their first and second "halves" will include (possibly among other things) the following:

```
| barrier             | first half                 | second half                |
|---------------------|----------------------------|----------------------------|
| barrier in buffer A | A0                         | A1, B0, B1, C0, C1, D0, D1 |
| barrier in buffer B | A0, A1, B0                 | B1, C0, C1, D0, D1         |
| barrier in buffer C | A0, A1, B0, B1, C0         | C1, D0, D1                 |
| barrier in buffer D | A0, A1, B0, B1, C0, C1, D0 | D1                         |
```

where for a buffer X, X0 is the set of action commands recorded in X prior to the barrier, and X1 is the set recorded after the barrier; and that, as a result, the command sets will appear to run as follows:

```
A0; then
A1 and B0; then
B1 and C0; then
C1 and D0; then
D1
```

--with all commands in each row of that table executing in no particular order, except insofar as their own special features may require it.

Is this the case?  Or does this only apply when command buffers A-D are submitted in four different `vkQueueSubmit` commands?  (Or does it not even apply then?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In accord with the version 1.0.35 of the Vulkan specification, command buffer boundaries don't have any effect on ordering between operations:

> Command buffer boundaries, both between primary command buffers of the same or different batches or submissions as well as between primary and secondary command buffers, do not introduce any implicit ordering constraints.  In other
>   words, submitting the set of command buffers (which can include executing secondary command buffers) between any semaphore or fence operations execute the recorded commands as if they had all been recorded into a single primary command buffer, except that the current state is reset on each boundary. Explicit ordering constraints can be expressed with events and pipeline barriers.

So, it does not matter if the CBs are primary/secondary, in the same/different batches, or in same/different submit commands. They all act as if they were one really big primary command buffer.

Therefore, synchronization works between all of these boundaries.

`vkQueueSubmit` tells us:

> Batches begin execution in the order they appear in pSubmits, but may complete out of order.

And `VkSubmitInfo` says, within a batch:

> The command buffers submitted in a batch begin execution *in the order they appear* in `pCommandBuffers`, but may complete out of order.

Emphasis added.

Given all of that, we know that it does not matter how you submit those batches. Whether you do it in 1 `vkQueueSubmit` or 4. Whether you do it in 1 batch of 4 CBs or 4 batches of 1 CB each. The only things that matter is the order in which those CBs are presented.

Which is why you should use as few `vkQueueSubmit` calls as you can possibly get away with. Because it will make no difference to the execution of your program, but it may make all the difference for *performance*.

Comment: I think I did at some point see that bit about buffers beginning execution in the order they appear within their batch's command buffer array, but I wasn't able to solidly connect that with the claim I wanted to confirm, which would be that any barriers within those buffers would behave as if the entire buffers were ordered.  Particularly, maybe two command buffers within a batch could begin in order but thereafter proceed in parallel somehow??  I dunno.  Maybe there's something else somewhere saying that that can't happen.

Comment: @mjwach: The point of the resolution of issue #300 is that, after submission to a queue, there *are no command buffers*. There are only the commands recorded into them. Barriers synchronize groups of commands as executed in a queue. For a barrier, there are only commands in the queue before it and commands in the queue after it. That is what the resolution of issue #300 means: that command buffers do not matter for synchronization purposes. Only the execution of the commands in the queue.

Comment: @mjwach: The Vulkan spec has been updated to fully specify all of this, so it is now very clear what the behavior should be.

Comment: I still don't see where they're 100% absolutely ruling out the possibility that commands from two buffers, even including barrier commands, could be interleaved unpredictably.  But that mention of state being reset on the "boundaries" does seem to indicate that they intend for this to be disallowed, since interleaving would make the "boundary" between two command buffers complex (or nonexistent, depending on one's perspective).  But still, every time I reread that "as if they had all been recorded into a single primary command buffer" bit I think, "Recorded in what order??"

Comment: I mean I think you're right though...  I'm just nitpicking about the wording of the specification, not disagreeing with this answer.

Comment: @mjwach: "*every time I reread that "as if they had all been recorded into a single primary command buffer" bit I think, "Recorded in what order??"*" The same order they were recorded into their respective CBs, ***as explicitly stated*** by the `vkQueueSubmit` command statement(s). I don't know how you could possibly get more clear than "in the order they appear".

Comment: @mjwach: "*I still don't see where they're 100% absolutely ruling out the possibility that commands from two buffers, even including barrier commands, could be interleaved unpredictably.*" I don't see the part where it says that it would be possible for commands on different sides of a barrier to be interleaved. Again, the whole "as if they had all been recorded into a single primary command buffer" thing.

Comment: They only "begin" execution in the order of appearance in the arrays, and after that the ordering of parts of them can change from the order of recording; hence the explicit statement that they can end out of order.  It's said elsewhere that within a command buffer, such reordering cannot violate barriers.  Here it's said that multiple command buffers combine in the queue as if they had been in one buffer to begin with, so AFTER that combination is done, execution-time reordering cannot violate barriers either.

Comment: But DURING that conceptual combination of the buffers, what happens? I'm not seeing a complete answer in these specification quotes. Barriers don't necessarily matter during that imaginary operation, because a barrier divides a single stream of enqueued commands, and here we are talking about two or more streams of commands that have not yet been enqueued. Each one must be kept ordered internally, and all of them must have their beginnings kept in buffer order, but a later command from one buffer might still cross a barrier from another buffer--not at execution time, but at "combination time".

Comment: ...Elsewhere, though, I do see that the explanations of the "halves" (now called "synchronization scopes") of synchronization commands have been updated to mention submission batches: "If vkCmdPipelineBarrier was recorded outside a render pass instance, the first synchronization scope includes every command submitted to the same queue before it, including those in the same command buffer and batch."  This helps cover the hole that I claim to be seeing.

Comment: @mjwach: "*but a later command from one buffer might still cross a barrier from another buffer--not at execution time, but at "combination time".*" No, it can't. There's no way to read "as if they had all been recorded into a single primary command buffer" in a way that would allow any command to suddenly move to a new location in the stream of commands to be executed. For any sequence of buffers, batches, and submits, you can convert it into a single primary CB that contains all of those commands in the same order, and you would get the same result. That's what "as if" means.

Comment: The programmer can reorder commands freely at programming time, of course.  Vulkan may reorder "as if" it were a programmer, to a very limited extent.  This reading is clear enough to me; but I'll take it up with Khronos if I find myself wishing for further resolution.