# Do I need two different queue submissions here?

Tags: vulkan

I have once command buffer 1, and command buffer 2. Both have had their recordings finished, and now I want to submit both of them, preferably in an efficient way (one vkQueueSubmit call.

The second command buffer needs to wait until the first one has completed. I thought that I could do this with one submit:

```
/* I THINK THE FOLLOWING IS WRONG */
VkSubmitInfo info;
info.pCommandBuffers = /* Pointer to the first command buffer */;
info.commandBufferCount = 2;
info.pSignalSemaphores = /* The first pointer value points to the semaphore 
that the first command buffer will signal when completed */
info.pWaitSemaphores = /* The second pointer value points to the same semaphore as above */
```

So I'm pretty sure the above is a wrong understanding, does that mean the only way in this case to have a dependency of the second command buffer on the first to have two different queue submissions? I mean two different VkSubmitInfo's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary semaphores are meant for *inter*queue communication. And while you can use timeline semaphores for intraqueue communications, for something like this, it's best to take a step back and ask yourself what is really going on.

Because it's not true that CB2 needs to wait for CB1 to complete. What's happening is that the result of some operation *within* CB1 needs to complete before some operation *within* CB2 can start. This is best accomplished with a `VkEvent`. CB1's operation can set an event that CB2 corresponding operation will wait on.

There's no need to separate these operations into different batches, let alone different queue submissions.

Comment: So you're saying to submit both command buffers in one VkSubmitInfo, and to record a vkCmdSetEvent() at the end of the first CB and a vkCmdWaitEvents at the start of the second CB? Will that mean that any subsequent commands in any subsequent command buffers submitted (because once submitted all become one stream of commands) will also be subject to the vkCmdWaitEvents in CB2? If so wouldn't a semaphore only block the second submit, and then any further submits won't have any restrictions ie., not wait on the event?

Comment: @Zebrafish: You seem to have missed the point of my second paragraph. You're still thinking in terms of dependencies between command buffers. Think instead of the dependencies of operations *within* those command buffers. A CB doesn't need to wait on another CB. The wait needs to be between some operation that generates data and some operation that consumes it. That these operations might be in different CBs is an unimportant detail.

Comment: Yes I thought I got that, set an event at the end of CB1 and a wait event at the start of CB2. But is it true that every command submitted thereafter on  subsequent submits will also wait on this event, because they come after.

Comment: @Zebrafish: "*set an event at the end of CB1 and a wait event at the start of CB2*" Again, you missed the point. Set an event after *whatever* it is that generates the data. Wait for the event *before* whatever it is that consumes it. That these might happen at the end/beginning of a CB is *irrelevant* for what you have to do. And you would use an event only if there is something between the two that should execute; otherwise, just use a barrier.

Comment: @Zebrafish: "*But is it true that every command submitted thereafter on subsequent submits will also wait on this event, because they come after.*" That depends on what is being waited on and what those commands will do (synchronization is per-pipeline stage), but you shouldn't assume the GPU will jump them ahead in execution just because they don't use the pipeline stages in the event wait operation.

Comment: "And you would use an event only if there is something between the two that should execute; otherwise, just use a barrier." I've just finished reading that a pipeline barrier only affects commands within the command buffer it's placed. It won't affect the commands in CB2, right?

Comment: What I mean is if I set an event in CB1 and a wait event in CB2, every command in each subsequent command buffer will wait for that event, right? However with a semaphore only CB2 waits, and any subsequent command buffers submitted won't wait for CB1. In some cases that may mean that commands in CB3 could start earlier with CB2 waiting on a semaphore rather than an event, because CB3 doesn't wait for the semaphore, however a wait event command affects everything downstream, including in different command buffers, right?

Comment: @Zebrafish: "*I've just finished reading that a pipeline barrier only affects commands within the command buffer*" Where did you read that? The standard certainly doesn't define the synchronization scopes of pipeline barriers (or events) that way. [Command buffers *do not matter* for synchronization purposes. Only submission order matters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39560367/734069).